# python thread does not recognize variable, local variable 'image' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, multithreading

```
for image in self._images:
            if image.ID == _id:
                if image.deletable:
                    # TODO: if deletable remove it also from Docker

                    def image_delete_thread():
                        image.destroy()
                        self._images.remove(image)
                        del image # this should in the end also delete the image if possible

                    thread.start_new_thread(image_delete_thread, ())

                    return make_response(jsonify({'success': 'Image >' + _id + '< deleting.'}), 202)
                return make_response(jsonify({'success': 'Image >' + _id + '< not deletable.'}), 400)
        return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Container image: >' + _id + '< not found!'}), 404)
```

I am getting following error: when the thread is executed. Why the new thread does not recognize the variable image?

local variable 'image' referenced before assignment

Comment: My two cents: I think it's because, although you define the function `image_delete_thread` within the scope of the for loop, the thread itself is not run in that same scope. This is fundamentally a new thread, so it is by definition not part of the scope from which it was invoked, and as such the image object is not available to the thread. Think of it as copy-pasting the `image_delete_thread` function to an empty file. If you were to run this file, the `image` object would not be defined. Passing objects around is one of the difficulties of multithreading. (Correct my if I'm wrong, of course)

Comment: I would guess that closures and threads don't work together well, but I'm not sure. Couldn't you pass the image as argument to the function?

Comment: Show us full traceback. We don't even know which line throws the error. Threads work correctly with closures and this kind of error should never happen. It may happen that `image` is no longer the object it is supposed to be but reference error is not possible.

Comment: You're not using functions correctly. Don't define `image_delete_thread()` inside a `for` loop. You don't pass any arguments to this function, so it won't necessarily know what `image` is. The multiple `return` statements are redundant. What are they supposed to be returning from? There's only one path out of `image_delete_thread()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because of

```
del image
```

line. The `del` operator is not doing what you think it does. Have a look at this:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def test():
...     x = 1
...     del x
... 
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           6 DELETE_FAST              0 (x)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now you can [read in docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-DELETE_FAST):

> DELETE_FAST(var_num)
>
> Deletes local co_varnames[var_num].

In other words `del` operator used on a variable (do not mistake it with `del x[idx]` operator) deletes the variable from locals. Since `image_delete_thread` shares its scope with the caller then that's why you get `ReferenceError`. Simple example:

```
>>> def test():
...     x = 1
...     del x
...     x += 1
...
>>> test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in test
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Remove `del image` line and it will be fine. There's no need for it anyway.

Comment: In the context of the unusual code presented, I'm not clear on how this causes the error. `image` is defined in a `for` loop, is it not continually redefined? After the caller, there is no further reference to `image` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) It works when I removed 'del image'

Comment: @roganjosh There is no reference to `image` in the caller but by scoping rules `image` is referenced by callee. In other words caller and callee share scopes (or at least common part of the outer scope). Once `image_delete_thread` function reaches `image.destroy()` it searches its own scope for `image` label. It is not there, so it searches callers scope. It is there, we are good. But once the other call to `image_delete_thread` deletes it via `del` operator then it throws `ReferenceError`. So the bad thing is that `del` operator affects callers scope as well.

Comment: @roganjosh It might not be exactly what happens under the hood. I still have few questions about that. But that's at least as far as I could analyze it without reading through Python's source code.

Comment: @freakish clearly your approach worked so you must be on to something and I appreciate your response :). But I'm still a bit confused on this one, so I have some learning to do. As I see it, `image` is defined by the `for` loop, it exists in the scope of `thread.start_new_thread`, gets passed to `image_delete_thread()` and then deleted. Nothing else uses `image` in the loop, so it completes, and then `image` springs back into existence. I have a disconnect somewhere in how it plays out.

Comment: @roganjosh `and then image springs back into existence` No, that's not what happens. What happens is this: for loop starts, `image` label is defined (i.e. stored in locals of the caller), `image_delete_thread` function is defined, `image_delete_thread` is fired in a separate thread, `image_delete_thread` searches its scope for `image` object and does the work. Note that this has a very bad side effect. Once the loop is done **all** `image_delete_thread` functions will run over **the same** image object.

Comment: Have a look at this code: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMTEFybmdsUllYU0E Note that when you run `main()` it will only print `4`. All earlier values of `i` were forgotten. The "binding" of outer variable to the inner function is always done lazily. That's why you have to pass variables as params, not via scoping rules. These are unintuitive and are dangerous.

Comment: @jisan Your code is still incorrect. There is a high chance that all `image_delete_thread` calls will run over **the same** `image` variable. You really have to pass `image` as a param to `image_delete_thread` (via `start_new_thread` call)

Comment: @roganjosh Perhaps I'm not clear enough. Note that if each thread runs during one iteration of `for` loop then this is fine. I assume that `image.destroy()` call takes some time, longer then the outer loop. In that case there's no more iterations of `for` loop to redefine `image`. So that's why I asked for the traceback, because I do believe that the `ReferenceError` is not on the first line of `image_delete_thread`. There's an important race condition here. Does this make sense? All of that is a bit fuzzy.

Comment: I went out and lost wifi sorry. I will look with fresh eyes tomorrow. It's probably something simple that I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

Add `nonlocal image` to the first line of `image_delete_thread`. If you are on Python 2.X, there are some proposed workarounds in [PEP 3104](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) which proposed the definition of `nonlocal`

Comment: Which requires Python3.x.